# Constrained Delaunay Triangulation Implementation for .NET

Tags: gratis, library, c#, .net

I am looking for an implementation (possibly wrapped into a library) for [Constrained Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation) that can be used from C#.

My only two requirements are:

- It must be somewhat efficient for simple concave polygons with polygonal holes (with less than 100 points in total).
- It must be gratis, also for inclusion in commercial closed-source applications.

*(Please note that I fully understand if there are no implementations that can be used for free. It is, however, a standard problem that appears to have some standard solutions, so I am using this question to find out whether, by any chance, there is already a suitable implementation.)*